# Angularjs adding dynamic form field for each categories

Tags: angularjs, forms, dynamic

Hi I have a Angularjs form where I am trying to add dynamic form field to each categories
eg:

**category1**
-Add Field
**category2**
-Add Field
**category3**
-Add Field
**category4**
-Add Field

my form

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in capital_budgets">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><% value.name %></label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">   
                <input 
                type="text"
                class="form-control input-sm" 
                ng-model="budget.capital_budget_category_id"
                >
            </div>

             <div class="clrfix"></div>

             <div ng-repeat="choice in choices">

                 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <input 
                   type="text" 
                   class="form-control input-sm" 
                   ng-model="budget.name">
                  </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <input 
                   type="text" 
                   class="form-control input-sm" 
                   ng-model="budget.budg" 
                   >
                </div>
              <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
            <div class="clrfix"></div>  
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="button" class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
           </div>
    </div>
```

and js

```
$scope.capital_budgets = [ {"id":1,"name":"Furniture & Fixture","alias":"furniture_fixture"}, {"id":2,"name":"Miscellaneous Property","alias":"miscellaneous_property"}, {"id":3,"name":"Office Equipment","alias":"office_equipment"}, {"id":4,"name":"Renovation","alias":"renovation"}, {"id":5,"name":"Vehicle","alias":"vehicle"} ]
    $scope.choices = [];

        $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
            var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
            $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
        };
        $scope.removeChoice = function() {
            var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
            $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
       };
```

I know it won't work.it only work for single category somebody help

Comment: Could you please add `capital_budgets` model data? So I can see how your iteration is working. Your problem is not very clear to me. Does the loop work and only the `ng-model` is not correctly working?

Comment: capital_budgets model data -.> [
{"id":1,"name":"Furniture & Fixture","alias":"furniture_fixture"},
{"id":2,"name":"Miscellaneous Property","alias":"miscellaneous_property"},
{"id":3,"name":"Office Equipment","alias":"office_equipment"},
{"id":4,"name":"Renovation","alias":"renovation"},
{"id":5,"name":"Vehicle","alias":"vehicle"}
]